# What's wrong with this racket code?

Tags: racket

I wrote this code (in full Racket) to find if one set is a subset of another, can you tell me what's wrong?

```
(struct myset (lst))

(define (member? a lst)
(cond
 [(empty? lst) false]
 [(equal? a (first lst)) true]
 [else (member? a (rest lst))]))

;; (subset? a b) determines if a is a subset of b
;; subset?: Set Set -> Bool
(define (subset? a b)
(cond
 [(empty? (myset-lst a)) true]
 [(empty? (myset-lst b)) false]
 [(member? (first (myset-lst a)) (myset-lst b))
  (subset? (rest (myset-lst a)) (myset-lst b))]
 [else false]))
```

Comment: Is it throwing an error?  If so what and where?  If no error, describe your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are changing the type of what you are passing as argument. In call to `subset?` you pass a struct with a list member. When recursing you pass the list `(rest (myset-lst a))` and the list `(myset-lst b)`. In the recursion it will try to do `(myset-lst a)` to get the list, but it will fail since `a` is not a myset struct but a list.

You should either just keep the sets as lists (not use structs) or you need to wrap the recursions, thus `(myset (rest (myset-lst a)))` to make a new set without the first element. Why you are changing `b` in the recursion is a mystery.

If you need structs you could just use a helper:

```scm
(define (subset? subset set)
  (define set-lst (myset-lst set))
  (define (helper subset-lst)
    ...)
  (helper (myset-lst subset)))
```